# Verifying Xcode is installed on High-Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, xcode

I am having [pip3 difficulty installing hidapi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59188993/4953146): a question was asked if Xcode is installed.

To [verify Xcode Installation instructions](https://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) provide two commands for verifying Xcode command tools:

> [image]

My tests:

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/
ls: /Applications/Xcode.app/: No such file or director

$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
ls: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs: No such file or directory

$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

$ gcc
clang: error: no input files

$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

## QUESTIONS

- Can I eliminate Xcode as the problem?
- Maybe Xcode is installed but
  needs to be configured?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367057/313842 I find my answer satisfying your queries about how xcodebuild is not usable. you need to reset the path, i.e. point it to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: @ankii  Please consider promoting your first response to an Answer.  I can then provide feedback

Comment: @ankii:  Good 'catch'.   I retested the  `ls -l /Applications/.../SDKs/` with the leading '/' character and posted the results at the top of the test list

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you provided tests only the installation of Command Line Tools which sit in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. However some software can require full Xcode app to work/install properly.

`xcode-select -p` Shows where the complier looks for packages. If this shows `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and the software installs properly, you don't need full app. But if the software needs it, you need to install Xcode App from the App Store or the website and update the path using

```bsh
sudo xcode-select -r
```

which resets it, or

```bsh
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

with appropriate path to Xcode.app.

Your test: `/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` highlights this issue. On my Mac, with Xcode app, it shows

```bsh
Xcode 10.3
Build version 10G8
```

So follow the instructions here

- [Download older version of Xcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252911/download-older-version-of-xcode)

to get the Xcode app, move it to appropriate place, run the path switching command with correct path to Xcode. And proceed with the installation.

@jmh: "X-code V 10.1 is the latest version of X-Code for High Sierra."

OP: "[Link to Xcode 10.1](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip)"