# Appstore does not save partially downloaded file

Tags: macos, catalina, xcode, mac-appstore

I upgraded to Catalina because I need Xcode 11. Now when Catalina was being downloaded, it continued from where it stopped even when there was network error. Now I am downloading Xcode with Appstore.

I started off since morning for over 6 hours only for the downloaded file not to find space to install. And When I deleted and clicked on it on the App Store. It started all over. That's 8 GB gone. I am in Lagos Nigeria and I don't have wonderful download speed. In case I encounter the space not enough again because I have deleted almost all apps I have just to make space for it, how do I make it use the already downloaded file so I won't go through this horrible experience again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use wget/ curl based methods and Apple Developer website for downloading it. I am not a fan of App Store managing huge downloads. Since I am not doing iOS development, I can work with old version too, so don't need App Store to recognise the download and give me an update.

- [Can't update Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode)
- [Download older version of Xcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252911/download-older-version-of-xcode/253269#253269)

I don't know about CURL, but in wget you can do

```
wget -c https://site
```

`-c` lets you continue the download where you started.

Reclaim the space using apps listed here:

- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space/5360?r=SearchResults&s=7|0.0000#5360)